# $something[$variable] use in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have seen some code like this:

```
$null = null;
$car = array(benz=>1040,maruthi=>180);
echo $car[$null]
```

I know the variable `$null` stores the value in `$car` array. I just need to know can we assign something like this

```
$car[$null] = $anynewvaribale .
```

I just need to know whether can we declare like that. Can we assign a new variable with a square bracket like that?

Comment: why do you want to set null to $null?

Comment: *"Can we assign a new variable with a square bracket like that?"* Yes, even with `null` though I wouldn't advise it

Comment: Put `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script and fix the notices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cases based on your assumption:-

```
$null       = null;
$car        = array(benz=>1040,maruthi=>180);
echo $car[$null];
```

You are assigning null key to `$car` array and not assigning any value then
output is null for `$car[$null]`

if assigning any value to null key

```
$null = null;
$car = array(benz=>1040,maruthi=>180);
$anynewvaribale = 'test';
$car[$null] = $anynewvaribale;
var_dump($car);
```

Output:

```
array(3) { ["benz"]=> int(1040) ["maruthi"]=> int(180) [""]=> string(4) "test" }
```

As per question `Can we assign a newvaribale with a square bracket like that` , yes you can assign variable like that.

[Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Why Down-vote ? Is something wrong in my answer?